# Как сымитировать POST-запрос

Tags: jquery, post, request, laravel5

В laravel5.5/jquery 3.2 приложении выполняется запрос на сервер

```
 $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'delete',
    headers: {
       'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    success: function(res) {
    ...
```

и в случае успешного возврата нужно перейти на другую страницу но с рядом параметров 
м не хочетсяч параметры отображать в урле поэтому

```
document.location= ‘/url?param=1’
```

не походит

Как-то несложно сымитировать POST-запрос можно?

MODIFIED :

1) да и принять запрос в laravel-control-e.
Вроде в таких случаях рисуют отдельную form-у с невидимыми(hidden) элементами action="POST" и генерят сабмит для нее.
Может есть что-то лучше ?

2) В js-кусочке вызывается laravel-control:

```
public function checkOutStorageSpace($id)
{
    app('StorageSpaceSer')->checkOutStorageSpaceById($id);
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully']);
}
```

А можно ли из этого контрола отправить POST-запрос с параметрами на другой урл и если да то как?
И не налетит ли земля на небесную ось от такого прогрпммирования ?

Comment: Сымитировать из html-кода? Или в виде get-параметров для приёма в php-файле?

Comment: Посмиотрите плиз блок MODIFIED

Comment: По поводу laravel ничего не скажу (не работаю с ним), но если бы речь шла о простом php-файле, в котором идет приём post-запроса, то в нем же на время тестирования можно организовать приём get-запросов. По сути массивы $_POST и $_GET — одно и тоже, поэтому вы можете смотреть наличие get-запроса и если он есть, использовать его. Если нет, то использовать post-данные. Это позволит вам тестировать через прямой вызов url с нужыми get-параметрами.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте ето

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

Comment: Пробовал. Но мне нужно не отправить ajax POST - запрос, а сабмитить всю страницу.

Comment: что вы имеете в виду?